# Formatting the XML of a list of objects using jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm new to Java and jaxb, so I'm sure the problem here is obvious.

I'm marshalling an object that looks like this:

```
public class Annotation {

    private RecipientCollection recipients;

    @XmlElement
    public RecipientCollection getRecipients() {
        return recipients;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement( name="Recipient" )
public class RecipientCollection extends ArrayList<Recipient> {
    @XmlElement(name="Recipient")
    private RecipientCollection recipients = this;
}

@XmlElement( name="Recipient" )
public class Recipient {

    private String value;
    private String name;

    @XmlElement( name="Recipient" )
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I need XML that looks like this:

```
<Annotation>
<recipients>
  <recipient>
    <RecipientName>test</RecipientName>
    <Recipient>test</Recipient>
  </recipient>
  <recipient>
    <RecipientName>test</RecipientName>
    <Recipient>test</Recipient>
  </recipient>
</recipients>
```

But I get XML that looks like this:

```
<Annotation>
<DeletableBy>Administrator,Recipient</DeletableBy>
<recipients>
    <RecipientName>test</RecipientName>
    <Recipient>test</Recipient>
</recipients>
<recipients>
    <RecipientName>test</RecipientName>
    <Recipient>test</Recipient>
</recipients>
```

Everything looked fine in the single recipient case, which (I think) is why it was implemented this way in the first place.  Any help?  I've been tweaking the bindings around for a while, but nothing works like I'm guessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
public class Annotation {

    private List<Recipient> recipients;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="recipients")
    @XmlElement(name="recipient")
    public List<Recipient> getRecipients() {
        return recipients;
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be 100% correct, except it made me realize I made a mistake with my question.  What's proper etiquette for that?  Modify the question and give you first dibs on a right answer?

Comment: @tallseth: Sure. If you can't infer a useful answer from what I've suggested, then modify the question.

Comment: Actually, looks like this will do it.  Thanks.